# System.DivideByZeroException: 'Attempted to divide by zero.'

Tags: c#, .net

so I do understand why i get this expetion thrown.
Because in my User class i have this bit off code.

```
            Console.WriteLine("Weight:"+Weight);
            int bmi = Weight / (Height * Height) * 10000;
            Console.WriteLine("Your Body Mass Index: " + bmi);
            Console.Write("That Means That you are: ");
            return Convert.ToInt32(bmi);
```

The error gets thrown when i press "2" in my main method:

```
        InitMenu();

        var userInput = Console.ReadKey();
        switch (userInput.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.D1:
                InitUser();
                InitGoals();
                break;
            case ConsoleKey.D2:
                menu.Disclamer();
                break;

        }
```

The Problem here is that my Programm thinks i allready called `InitUser();` Where I indeed ask for the Users Height and Weight which is needed for the BMI calculation.

And that is because the user didn't input any information. Which is done by pressing 1 not 2.

By pressing 2 i only want to display the disclaimer message.

Here it's how it should work:

- Show menu
- Choose Option (in this case 2)
- Show Disclamer
- Exit to Menu Again.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `the problem somehow he thinks the 2 first Methods where allready called` please update the question to be a little more clear and specific as its hard to understand what you mean

Comment: I updated the text, i hope is make more sense now. Yes i know that Those are 0. I explaied it better now.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In C#, integers default to 0 value. Your variables are not initialized.